# Why is Eclipse (Kepler) attempting to run this Weblogic class when saving my HTML?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

Every time I make a change to some HTML I am editing, this error
comes up:

```
Errors occurred during the build.
Errors running builder 'Faceted Project Validation Builder' on project 'CateredToYou'.
Could not initialize class oracle.eclipse.tools.weblogic.server.WebLogicServerRuntimeComponentType
```

I'd like to figure out why the error comes up despite the fact that I am not doing any J2EE development at the moment

OR

how can I shut off whatever is trying to execute this command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I accidentally deleted the Java 1.6 needed for Eclipse when I allowed the Java auto update.
As it turns out, the jdk1.6 was not deleted from the system but it was not in the "Installed JRE's" list
I added the JRE, but was still getting the error. I added the jdk to the config and the error went away.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a builder that is configured on the project is having problems.

Open the `Properties` for the project and look in `Builders`. You will see a list of the builders configured for the project which should include 'Faceted Project Validation Builder'. You can disable it by clearing the check box or remove it entirely.

Comment: I'd rather fix the problem than "unhook the battery".
But "shut off" I mean fix the problem.